# Is there a way to merge the results of many QuerySets into a single QuerySet in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a list of QuerySets (qs1, qs2, ..., qsn), whose length is not fixed (it varies depending on other variables). I need to merge all those QuerySets into a single QuerySet. I have something like this:

```
list1 = [qs1, qs2, ..., qsn]
```

I know there's a function in Django that allows me to do just this, but only if I know exactly how many QuerySets I want to join. Since in this case the number of QuerySets in the list (the ones that I want to merge) varies, I can't use

```
qs1.union(qs2, qs3)
```

because I won't always have just those three QuerySets in my list, sometimes I'll have just one or just two, or a thousand.

Knowing that the length of the list is not fixed and that I need a final QuerySet that includes the results of all of the QuerySets within the list `list1`, no matter how many QuerySets it contains, is there a function that allows me to merge all the QuerySets inside this list into a single QuerySet? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#union), you can use `qs1.union(*queryset_list)`